# How container width is calculated in bootstrap for different devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am just starting with Bootstrap and going through docs. Right now, seems very confusing and have some queries as follows:

1. In the [Grid Options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) table, why the container width is always less than device width, why not equal to device width for e.g.Small devices Tablets (≥768px).
2. How the width 750px is determined, why not 743px or 755px or any other size. How did they determine that 750px as container width.
3. As given, bootstrap scales up to 12 columns with gutter between columns and each column width is
   ~62px and gutter is 30px (15px on each side) therefore 
   (12(cols)*62px ) + (11(gutters) * 15(width))  equals to 909px instead of the given 750px container width. Why ?

This is all is very confusing to me. Could someone plz show how the container widths are calculated for different breakpoints and why the container width is not equal to device width ?

Thanks
dk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bootstrap `.container` is used as a centered container, if you want full-width on all devices use `.container-fluid`

The 62px is actually 62.5px at the small breakpoint. 62.5 x 12 = 750px, and this includes the 15px padding around each column. The gutter is within the column since padding is used (as opposed to a margin where the gutter would be outside the column).

Here's a nice visual demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/Sul9kw8Kne

Aside from the container width, take a look at this [article about the BS3 grid](http://blog.codeply.com/2016/04/06/how-the-bootstrap-grid-really-works/)

Answer (score 0):

First of, If you want a container to equal to device width use

```
container-fluid instead of container
```

For the Grid system there are two concepts

- Boxed layout (.container provide this)
- wide layout (.container-fluid provide this)

in bootstarp there is no pixels for grid every thing in in percentage (%) only.
all media quire break points are setup through bootstartp it self you may change those values through bootstrap customizer http://getbootstrap.com/customize/.